# Two lines with the same ip destination in routing table

Tags: networking, routing

I am studing a particular case in routing table. As the title i have this table for a particular router in a net:

```
destin.IP       Mask             NextHop            Interface
193.14.5.160    255.255.255.0    ---.---.---.---    m0
193.14.5.192    255.255.255.0    ---.---.---.---    m1
111.0.0.0       255.0.0.0        ---.---.---.---    m0
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
194.17.21.0     255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
194.17.21.16    255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
194.17.21.0     255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
194.17.21.16    255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0          111.30.31.18       m0
```

In that table there are lines with the same IP address like

```
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
```

and

```
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
```

in this case which of the two lines is chosen for routing? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: see the ex. number two 2 https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1w3h0e7wp4eyb6/PSR-Esercitazione-Integrativa.pdf?dl=0

Comment: the ex. n.2 ask to write a routing table for router R1 in the network

Comment: What router / operating system is the routing done on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your linux kernel configuration (loaded modules) either A) the first one will be used or B) some kind of load sharing will be performed.

Comment: Sorry, this is either incomplete or just wrong. For one, the question doesn't mention Linux _anywhere_. (Even if guessing based on how the example table looks, it's most definitely not Linux nor BSD.) For another, even on Linux, this does not depend on loaded modules (_which_ modules, by the way?) – identical routes have an explicit preference setting (the route metric), and 'load sharing' only happens if an explicit multi-gateway route is created.